# App to App communication in Sharepoint(sharepoint hosted App)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I have two app parts in a page which needs to communicate with each other. Is there is any way to have this?

Comment: Postmessage is what you're looking for. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richard_dizeregas_blog/archive/2014/05/07/connected-sharepoint-app-part.aspx

Comment: When i use post message i have access denied permission issue while using postmessage is there is other way

Comment: if you can describle your implementation around @Akhoy's suggestion in a bit more detail, it will help us sort your issue out better. Just click on edit, and update the post.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think of is having an list in the host. You can have both the apps create/update entries to it, and this can facilitate communications between them.

for example,

> Consider App `A` to track tickets for any user, and App `B` to send mails etc. So for any new ticket into the system, `A` creates a new entry into the `host list` with status `open`. Then periodically, `B` fetches all entires with status `open`, takes necessary action (send mail etc.) and then updates them to `close`.

If you can describe your scenario in a bit more details, I can give a more specific solution.